# jquery how to find a div that has a certain id?

Tags: jquery, get

lets say i have this:

```
<div id="256" class="testt1"><li>test1</li></div>
<div id="126" class="testt2"><li>test2</li></div>
```

how can i find the div with id 256. The thing is that i don't know those id's, they are created on the fly. So i'm thinking:

```
var get_it = $('div.testt1').attr('id');
```

but then how do i find that `div` if i want to remove it or something?

Comment: ID's starting with numerics are not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you obtain the ID just concatenate it into a selector using `+`:

```
var get_it = $('div.testt1').attr('id');
$('#' + get_it).doStuff();
```

Comment: If $("div.test1") gives the required element why query for the same element using ID again?

Comment: @Cybernate: Ask the OP, not me.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is "how can i find the div with id 256", not "how can I find the id of a div with class testt1".

Comment: Yeah, but question titles are a pain to come up with; he also said "The thing is that i don't know those id's, they are created on the fly."

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#256') //<<-- the div with id 256
```

if you dont know the id make a fn for finding it:

```
function find_id(selector, id){

   $(selector).each(function(){
        if(this.id == id){
             return this;
        }
   })

}

//and use it like so:

var div = $(find_id('.testt1', '256')); //this is the dom element with id 256
```

Comment: i understand that, but i don't actually know it

Comment: This works if you know the ID already, but Patrioticcow states that he doesn't know the ID in advance, so it would need to be obtained somehow first, something like BoltClock's method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know for sure you are getting the div you want since multiple divs with the same class.  This will get you the first one it finds:

```
$('div.testt1:eq(0)')
```

Comment: Calling `attr()` on a set of elements returns based on `eq(0)`